# How to fix typescript error for 'possibly null' prop in child component, which will render only when prop is defined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Suppose the following:

```
type TDictionary = {
  MAIN_TITLE: string;
  COMPONENT_A_TITLE: string;
  COMPONENT_B_TITLE: string;
} | null;

const ComponentA: React.FC<{ dictionary: TDictionary }> = React.memo(
  ({ dictionary }) => {
    return <div>{dictionary.COMPONENT_A_TITLE}</div>;
  }
);

const ComponentB: React.FC<{ dictionary: TDictionary }> = React.memo(
  ({ dictionary }) => {
    return <div>{dictionary.COMPONENT_B_TITLE}</div>;
  }
);

const App = React.memo(() => {
  const [dictionary, setDictionary] = React.useState<TDictionary>(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setDictionary({
        MAIN_TITLE: "Hello world",
        COMPONENT_A_TITLE: "Hello from ComponentA",
        COMPONENT_B_TITLE: "Hello from ComponentB"
      });
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  if (!dictionary) return <div>loading...</div>;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{dictionary.MAIN_TITLE}</h1>
      <ComponentA dictionary={dictionary} />
      <ComponentB dictionary={dictionary} />
    </div>
  );
});
```

Typescript keeps thinking that `dictionary` could be null at some point in the code, but clearly that's impossible. How can I fix this? The only way that I can think of is changing the interfaces for `ComponentA` and `ComponentB` to `Exclude<TDictionary, null>`, but that seems like an extra step?

[image: lucid-black-b90v4c]

Comment: Since, `TDictionary` is defined as `{ .... }  | null`, it technically could be null. You can instead remove `null` from `TDictionary` and change `useState<TDictionary>(null)` to `useState<TDictionary | null>(null)`

Comment: Use Non null assertion operator `!` in your components.
`return <div>{dictionary!.COMPONENT_A_TITLE}</div>;`
notice the `!` after `dictionary`